# Rotating UILabel

Tags: ios, rotation, uilabel

I'm trying to rotate an UILabel at a custom angle; i tried every solution found but i end up with the same problem.

I have `label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 340, 75, 102);` and when i apply the rotation

> label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 3.2);

The result label has the correct angle but it's frame is not the same size; the frame resulted is:

```
-25.738834 71.485809 126.477669 119.028381
```

Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

From Apple's guid and documentations:

> The transform property is used to animate or move the entire view in
>   complex ways. For example, you would use a transform to rotate or
>   scale the view. If the current transform is not the identity
>   transform, the frame property is undefined and should be ignored.
>   Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html